# Use VBA to create Internal Page Links in a PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, hyperlink

I am trying to create hyperlinks to specific pages within a PDF that is created in Excel with the ExportedAsFixedFormat command. My goal is to have hyperlinks on the first page of the PDF that will take the viewer to certain pages within the document. It is easy enough to do with Adobe Acrobat, but the hyperlink's display text changes regularly along with the number of links, so I need this to be automated each time a PDF is generated from Excel.

I have successfully used Hyperlinks.Add and can create a hyperlink within the PDF that opens a PDF to a specific page. But every time the link is clicked it opens the same PDF in Internet Explorer. I just need the PDF that contains the hyperlink to remain open in Acrobat and go to the specified page number.

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, _
  Address:="file:\\\C:\Test PDF.pdf", _
  SubAddress:="Page=2", TextToDisplay:="Test"
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, _
      Address:="", SubAddress:="Page=2", TextToDisplay:="Test"
```